# Semantic markup for fieldset alternative

Tags: html, markup, semantic-markup, wai-aria, fieldset

`<fieldset>` is awesome because it has 3 super features. **It...**

1. becomes `:disabled` via `disabled=""`
2. supports `<legend>`
3. provides semantic grouping

**But...** I have situations where `<fieldset>` breaks layout

So I'm resorting to `<div>` and seeking an [ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/) `role`

Or any reasonable markup alternative

```
<div aria-disabled="false">
  What role could this have to simulate fieldset
</div>
```

1. Seems solvable via `aria-disabled`
2. Seems solvable via heading inside. Or via `<figure>`?
3. Is there a generic grouping `role` that could be used?
   `<div>` `<figure>` or `<section>`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on **how** exactly `<fieldset>` breaks your layout? It's supported in all browsers (though `:disabled` is spotty in IE). Could you please share a code sample and denote which browsers it works on and which browsers it doesn't work on? And do you have any constraints? Like would a CSS solution suffice?

Comment: @ObsidianAge One possible cause could be that `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` cannot be flex containers.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the "group" role

```
<div role="group" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="fieldset_title">
  <div id="fieldset_title">Title</div>
  <div>element1</div>
  <div>element2</div>
</div>
```

You can find more examples on the following page:
[Using grouping roles to identify related form controls](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_grouping_roles_to_identify_related_form_controls)